# Spring MessageSource: access message file within dependency jar

Tags: java, spring-mvc, internationalization

I have a Spring MVC application using **i18n**. Now I want to use a message file provided within a dependency. I want to use the same keys/values to have consistent output in my application. But somehow it does not work... What am I missing?

My ResourceHandler:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/");
}
```

My MessageSource:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    source.setBasenames("messages/user/login/login",
                        "messages/user/user",
                        //external file (NOT WORKING)
                        "classpath:messages/enums/enums");
    source.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return source;
}
```

Location of the message.file starting from the `war` root:

```
WEB-INF/lib/utils-0.1.jar/messages/enums/enums_en.properties
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to change two things to get it to work:

1. I needed `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` and not `ResourceBundleMessageSource`.
2. After changing the source class, `classpath:` had to be added to all base names. There is no difference between the local "resource" files and files inside dependencies.

The final code looks like this:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    source.setBasenames("classpath:messages/user/login/login",
                        "classpath:messages/user/user",
                        //external file (in utils-0.1.jar)
                        "classpath:messages/enums/enums");
    source.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return source;
}
```